# Jenkins: get email-ext working with token macro plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins (v2.163) installed and I'm using the plugins email-ext as well as the token macro plugin.
The documentation page of the token macro plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Token+Macro+Plugin) tells me that a couple of plugins (that I'm using) like PMD, Warnings, Checkstyle, etc. produce tokens which are also listed on the project configuration page when I click on "Content Token Reference".

Some of the tokens I like to use are CHECKSTYLE_COUNT or PMD_COUNT.

My mail-content for the email-notification looks like this:

```
Branch: ${GIT_BRANCH}
$DEFAULT_CONTENT

Checkstyle issues: ${CHECKSTYLE_COUNT} (${CHECKSTYLE_NEW} new, ${CHECKSTYLE_FIXED} fixed)
Duplicate code issues: ${DRY_COUNT} (${DRY_NEW} new, ${DRY_FIXED} fixed)
Mess Detector issues: ${PMD_COUNT} (${PMD_NEW} new, ${PMD_FIXED} fixed)

Failed tests:
${FAILED_TESTS}
```

But all token that are supposed to be filled be the corresponding plugins stay empty (while others are filled), so the resulting mail looks like this:

```
Branch: origin/stage

PROJECT - Build # 1 - Successful:

Check console output at http(...) to view the results.

Checkstyle issues:  ( new,  fixed)
Duplicate code issues:  ( new,  fixed)
Mess Detector issues:  ( new,  fixed)

Failed tests:
No tests ran.
```

Am I missing a specific configuration for the tokens to be set?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the $ signs like \${CHECKSTYLE_COUNT} ?

Comment: I just did, doing so will disable the parsing of the escaped variables, so instead of an empty value I will get "\${CHECKSTYLE_COUNT}" in plaintext.

Comment: This is interesting.  I have to escape my tokens, or I get groovy errors.  But when I do, I get the same thing you see, with "No tests ran." in place of ${FAILED_TESTS}.